# Create a functioning Response object

Tags: python, python-requests

For testing purposes I'm trying to create a Response() object in python but it proves harder then it sounds.

i tried this:

```
from requests.models import Response

the_response = Response()
the_response.code = "expired"
the_response.error_type = "expired"
the_response.status_code = 400
```

but when I attempted `the_response.json()` i got an error because the function tries to get `len(self.content)` and `a.content` is null.
So I set `a._content = "{}"` but then I get an encoding error, so I have to change `a.encoding`, but then it fails to decode the content....
this goes on and on. Is there a simple way to create a Response object that's functional and has an arbitrary status_code and content?

Comment: Have you considered using something like [`responses`](https://github.com/getsentry/responses)? Alternatively, create a [`mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) rather than trying to recreate the real object

Answer (score 109, accepted):

That because the `_content` attribute  on the `Response` objects (on python3) has to be bytes and not unicodes.

Here is how to do it:

```
from requests.models import Response

the_response = Response()
the_response.code = "expired"
the_response.error_type = "expired"
the_response.status_code = 400
the_response._content = b'{ "key" : "a" }'

print(the_response.json())
```

Comment: This will work, but breaks if `requests` changes the implementation of `Response`; the leading underscore indicates an internal detail that shouldn't be relied upon. That said, it hasn't changed for a while (and such a change may also affect how `responses` does its thing, unless it mocks the public interface too).

Comment: 100% agreed, but as for OP question - this is the right solution. Also upvoted your mock solution(much better than 3th party lib), but again the OP asked for specific use case and wanted to know why his code is not working.

Comment: Incidentally, why start with `Response()`? Can't you provide some of those parameters like `Response(data={...}, status=code)` etc?

Comment: @NeilG the `requests.models.Response` class does not take parameters during initialization.   See - https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/main/requests/models.py#L659

Answer (score 50):

Create a [`mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) object, rather than trying to build a real one:

```
from unittest.mock import Mock

from requests.models import Response

the_response = Mock(spec=Response)

the_response.json.return_value = {}
the_response.status_code = 400
```

Providing a `spec` ensures that the mock will complain if you try to access methods and attributes a real `Response` doesn't have.

Comment: Didn't work for me, I got AttributeError: Mock object has no attribute 'streaming'.

Answer (score 5):

Same as what was in the accepted answer but you can use the `raw` attribute instead of the `_content` *private* attribute (as that is an internal detail of the library):

```py
from io import BytesIO
from requests.models import Response

the_response = Response()
the_response.code = "expired"
the_response.error_type = "expired"
the_response.status_code = 400

the_response.raw = BytesIO(b'{ "key" : "a" }')

print(the_response.json())
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use the [`responses`](https://github.com/getsentry/responses) library to do it for you:

```
import responses

@responses.activate
def test_my_api():
    responses.add(responses.GET, 'http://whatever.org',
                  json={}, status=400)

    ...
```

This has the advantage that it intercepts a real request, rather than having to inject a response somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach by using the [`requests_mock`](https://requests-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library, here with the provided fixture:

```py
import requests


def test_response(requests_mock):
    requests_mock.register_uri('POST', 'http://test.com/', text='data', headers={
        'X-Something': '1',
    })
    response = requests.request('POST', 'http://test.com/', data='helloworld')

    ...
```