# Create response with file as content

Tags: python, request, httprequest

I'd like to create an http response with an mp4 video as the content
Following the advice I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40361308/create-a-functioning-response-object) this is what I have so far:

```py
    resp = Response()
    resp.status_code = 200
    with open("unit_tests/unit_test_data/testvid 2 - public_2.mp4", "rb") as vid:
        resp._content = vid.read(1024 * 1024)
    resp.headers = {"content-length": "13837851"}
```

This response is then to be used as follows :

```py
    with open(fname, "wb") as file:
        for data in resp.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
            size = file.write(data)
```

However in the second part, when trying to read the content of my response I get the following error:

```
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Any help is welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here are multiple snippets for the logic that can  help you. (not tested, so might need some corrections)

```
myFileNameToSend = "unit_tests/unit_test_data/testvid 2 - public_2.mp4"
```

Step 1: Encode the file you want to send as base64 string

```
import base64
myFileToSend = open(myFileNameToSend, 'rb')
myFileContent = myFileToSend.read()
myFileStringToSend = base64.b64encode(myFileContent).decode('ascii')
```

Step 2: Actually sending the string over as response

```
from fastapi import Request,FastAPI, File, UploadFile, Form
import requests
api = FastAPI()
@api.get("/test") #this is where your webserver is listening for post requests
def test():
    return {"filename": myFileNameToSend.split("/")[-1],"dataAsAscii":myFileStringToSend}
```

Step 3: Decoding base64 string back to bytes

```
import json
import base64
import requests
jsonReceived = initialRequest.json() #initialRequest is your request object to which you are expecting to get a response
myFileNameReceived = jsonReceived["filename"]
myFileStringReceived = jsonReceived["dataAsAscii"].encode('ascii')
myFileReceived = base64.b64decode(myFileStringReceived)
f = open(myFileNameReceived, 'wb')
f.write(myFileReceived)
f.close()
```