# AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'streaming' in packages\django\middleware\common.py

Tags: python, django, python-requests

Using [requests](https://github.com/psf/requests) we are unable to get a 200 success code due to either a bug in the common file or a wrong way of sending the request or receiving the response.
Here are the technical details:

**Calling script**

```
import requests
try:
 post_data = {'langs': langs, 'langs_json': []}
 # filling post_data..
 response = requests.post(api_call_url, json=post_data, verify=False)
return JsonResponse({}, safe=False, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
except Exception as e:
return JsonResponse({}, safe=False, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

**Serving script**

```
@csrf_exempt
def api_end_point(request):
    try:
        data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8-sig'))
        with open(os.path.join(r'assets\i18n', f'fr.json'), 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
            json.dump(data['langs_json'][0], f)
        with open(os.path.join(r'assets\i18n', f'en.json'), 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
            json.dump(data['langs_json'][1], f)
        # All works above.. the issue has something to do with the response itself..
        response = JsonResponse(dict(status=True), safe=False, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        response.status_code = 200 # trying to solve..
        return response
    except Exception as e:
        response = JsonResponse(dict(status=False), safe=False, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
        response.status_code = 500 # trying to solve..
        return response
```

**Error msg**

```
  File "C:\Users\***\Desktop\****\*****\*****\venv\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\common.py", line 112, in process_response
if not response.streaming and not response.has_header('Content-Length'):
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'streaming'
```

**common.py snippet**

```
    def process_response(self, request, response):
    """
    When the status code of the response is 404, it may redirect to a path
    with an appended slash if should_redirect_with_slash() returns True.
    """
    # If the given URL is "Not Found", then check if we should redirect to
    # a path with a slash appended.
    if response.status_code == 404 and self.should_redirect_with_slash(request):
        return self.response_redirect_class(self.get_full_path_with_slash(request))

    # Add the Content-Length header to non-streaming responses if not
    # already set.
    if not response.streaming and not response.has_header('Content-Length'):
        response.headers['Content-Length'] = str(len(response.content))

    return response
```

Comment: `'Response' object ...` means that it's not a Django response (`HttpResponse`) that you return. Is your "calling script" a Django view as well?

Comment: In your script, you return a response object gotten from the call [`requests.post(•••)`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.post) within the `try` block and within the `catch` block you returned [`JsonResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects). Mind you, the [Response](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response) from `requests.post(•••)` is of a different type from [`JsonResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script, you return a [`Response`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response) object gotten from the call to [`requests.post(•••)`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.post) within the `try` block. Mind you this `Response` object is one defined by [requests Python library](https://pypi.org/project/requests/). 
Then within the `catch` block you return [`JsonResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) which [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) defines. 
Do you see the error now? The `Response` from `requests.post(•••)` is of a different type from `JsonResponse`. They originate from two different libraries/frameworks.

Comment: Coincidentally; both `requests.Response` and `JsonResponse` have the same attribute `status_code`. Python being dynamically typed doesn’t matter. But when it looks for `streaming` attribute, only `JsonResponse` has it.

Comment: Interesting, I've found this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40361308/create-a-functioning-response-object talking about the Response object and started building it by hand. I still can't build it right.. every element I add brings about another missing element.. so I'm trying with resposes now

Comment: The fact that you will still return the object via `def api_end_point(request)` which is a Django view is another check point. [Every Django view must return a Django `HttpResponse` object.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse) [Even Django’s helper method `render()` that renders templates returns a `HttpResponse` when called.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) So key point: **using Django’s views means you must return Django’s `HttpResponse`.**